# Compact opens in sober $T_1$ are closed?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I am trying to establish some basic facts about spectral spaces. In relation to this I am looking for a proof of, or a counter example to, the statement that compact open subsets of a sober $T_1$ space are closed.

Recall that a topological space is *sober* if every closed irreducible subset has a generic point. Whence in a sober $T_1$ space the closed irreducible subsets are precisely the singletons.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find counterexamples in some fairly typical sober $T_1$ spaces that are not Hausdorff.  For example, consider $\mathbb{N}\cup\{x,y\}$ where every point of $\mathbb{N}$ is isolated and the neighbourhoods of $x$ and $y$ are the cofinite subsets containing $x$ and $y$ respectively.  Then $\mathbb{N}\cup\{x\}$ is compact open but not closed.

Comment: So we are considering the two point compactification of the natural numbers?